# Clean-up duplicates from the same dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Am using Pycharm but it detected some code duplicates in my code, but the tricky bit, the duplicates are within a dictionary constant , how can I solve this in the dictionary itself to remove the duplicates :

Below is my code :

```
    CONSTANT = {
    GMBH_CO_KGAA: {
        OWNER_PREFIX: {
            'min': 2,
            'max': None,
            'roles': [ROLE_OWNER_PERSON, ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY],
        }
    },
    GMBH_CO_KG: {
        OWNER_PREFIX: {
            'min': 2,
            'max': None,
            'roles': [ROLE_OWNER_PERSON, ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY],
        }
    }
}
```

They show that **GMBH_CO_KGAA** is a duplicate of **GMBH_CO_KG** , how can I clean up this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution

```
EXTRACTED = {
        'OWNER_PREFIX': {
            'min': 2,
            'max': None,
            'roles': [ROLE_OWNER_PERSON, ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY],
        }
    }

    CONSTANT = {
        'GMBH_CO_KGAA': EXTRACTED,
        'GMBH_CO_KG': EXTRACTED
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way but it works:

```py
ROLE_OWNER_PERSON = 'person'
ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY = 'company'

CONSTANT = {
    'GMBH_CO_KGAA': {
        'OWNER_PREFIX': {
            'min': 2,
            'max': None,
            'roles': [ROLE_OWNER_PERSON, ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY],
        }
    },
    'GMBH_CO_KG': {
        'OWNER_PREFIX': {
            'min': 2,
            'max': None,
            'roles': [ROLE_OWNER_PERSON, ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY],
        }
    }
}

####### Solution #######

no_duplicated_dict = {}

for key,value in CONSTANT.items():
    if value not in no_duplicated_dict.values():
        no_duplicated_dict[key] = value
        
print(no_duplicated_dict)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, however, I just wanted to clean up the code and I try to come up with cleaner code without duplicates, according to what you provided, it's like it removes entrielyy the duplicate , I want to have a way of cleaning up that dict

Comment: Maybe like creating a placeholder for the duplicates but when it's sharable within the dict

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Isn't there a way of refactoring that dict, so that I don't have duplicated code

Comment: That is exactly what I did in my code, re-build the dict without duplicates. Or... what you say is that you wrote that dict yourself with duplicated values within the code and you want to process your written code?

Comment: Kindly check the solution I have posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***[deepdiff](https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/)***,  I find it very convenient for getting diff of (nested) objects in general and clean code :

Installation :

```
pip install deepdiff
```

then

```
import deepdiff
import json
ROLE_OWNER_PERSON = 'person'
ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY = 'company'

GMBH_CO_KGAA= {
        'OWNER_PREFIX': {
            'min': 3,
            'max': None,
            'roles': [ROLE_OWNER_PERSON, ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY],
        }
    }
GMBH_CO_KG= {
        'OWNER_PREFIX': {
            'min': 2,
            'max': None,
            'roles': [ROLE_OWNER_PERSON, ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY],
        }
    } 
          

diff = deepdiff.DeepDiff(GMBH_CO_KGAA, GMBH_CO_KG)
print(json.dumps(diff, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
"values_changed": {
    "root['OWNER_PREFIX']['min']": {
        "new_value": 2,
        "old_value": 3
       }
    }

}
```

But if both are similar :

```
GMBH_CO_KGAA= {
    'OWNER_PREFIX': {
        'min': 2,
        'max': None,
        'roles': [ROLE_OWNER_PERSON, ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY],
    }
}
GMBH_CO_KG= {
        'OWNER_PREFIX': {
            'min': 2,
            'max': None,
            'roles': [ROLE_OWNER_PERSON, ROLE_OWNER_COMPANY],
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
{}
```